# Copy new files to another folder on windows automatically

Tags: shell, copy, watch

I have a folder where some xml files keep updated, I want those files copied to another folder. From which a software collects the xml. I want to watch the folder and copy only new files as it comes to another folder automatically.

Is there any ready made solution or can it be done using Autoit, shell script or vb.net(last choice).

**Main concerns:**

- Know when a file is added.
- Copy them to the folder.
- Make sure its notcopied second time.

If I schedule this code, it might also work

```
cd /home/webapps/project1/folder1 for f in *.csv do     cp -v $f
/home/webapps/project1/folder2/${f%.csv}$(date +%m%d%y).csv done
```

But it again don't have a way to not copy those which are already copied.

Answer (score 1):

[rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/). Put it into cron to run every few minutes.